# Point Heroku app subpage to its own custom domain

Tags: heroku, flask, dns, html

I have a bunch of heroku apps built on Flask, each of which have their own custom domain with pretty low traffic.

I was wondering if it is possible to group them all in one single app with multiple subpages, and point each subpage to its own domain.

This is what I currently have:

```
app1.herokuapps.com ---> www.app1.com
app2.herokuapps.com ---> www.app2.com
app3.herokuapps.com ---> www.app3.com
```

This is what I want:

```
app.herokuapps.com/app1 ---> www.app1.com
app.herokuapps.com/app2 ---> www.app2.com
app.herokuapps.com/app3 ---> www.app3.com
```

Is this possible? I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Any Heroku domain pointing on an app will go straight to root.

However, you could detect which hostname the request is coming from within your app's code, and serve one page or another one from there.

```
from flask import request

if request.headers.get('Host') == "www.app1.com":
  return render_template('app1')
elif request.headers.get('Host') == "www.app2.com":
  render_template('app2')
else:
  render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if this arrangement is compatible with having a good SEO on each site?

Comment: That will happen server-side. So as far as the search engine will know, each domain will be different. It shouldn't cause any SEO problems.